# Check the convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(x)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check the domain of $R$ for 
$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(x)^n$$
so what I did is to take $a_n$ and he is $1$ so $\rightarrow -1<x<1$
$$ -1<\ln(x)<1 \longrightarrow \frac{1}{e} < x < e$$ now lets check the left and right sides
for $e$ its Diverging and my problem is with $\frac{1}{e}$ how I check him?
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to 0} \left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)^n$$ how I can write it? and what its give to me?
Thanks!

Comment: Mixing pronouns with math is confusing. What is $a_n$?

Comment: this is the general organ, how you call it?

Comment: for $\frac{1}{e}$ its $-1^{n}$?

Comment: For $1/e$ you are looking at $\sum (-1)^n$. Now is the answer clear?

Comment: Yes. Thanks now its ok.

Comment: What is $R$? You wrote "I'm trying to check the domain of $R$".

Comment: @OfirAttia, it sounds like you're trying to translate from hebrew: "האיבר הכללי"= the general term (of the series)

Comment: yes, I didnt find the word at the moment. thanks.

Comment: What is $x$, in the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to work with geometric series:

$$|\log x|<1\iff \frac1e<x<e\;\implies\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log^nx\;\;\text{converges}$$

$$|\log x|\ge 1\iff 0<x<\frac1e\;\;or\;\;x>e\;\implies\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log^nx\;\;\text{diverges}$$

The above is assuming you meant $\,\log(x)^n=(\log x)^n\;$ , as hinted in the last part of your question.

Comment: Should $x>3$ be $x>e$?

Comment: It should be $\,e\,$, of course. Thanks for the catch.